# Redirecting to 404 route in PhalconPHP results in Blank Page

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have setup a router, and in it, defined a route for 404s:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;
$router = new Router(FALSE);
$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);

$route = $router->add('/', ['controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index']);
$route->setName("index");

// other routes defined here...

$router->notFound([
  "controller" => "index",
  "action" => "route404"
]);

?>
```

My IndexController:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
    // code removd for berevity 
    }

    public function route404Action() {
      // no code here, I just need to show the view.
    }

}
?>
```

And I have a view @ `/app/views/index/route404.phtml` that just has a bit of HTML in it, I even tried making it a `.volt` file, no luck.

When I go to a page that doesn't match any routes, it works fine.  But, if I try to redirect to it, I just get a blank page.  For example, in one of my controllers I have this:

```
if (!$category) {
  // show 404

  //Tried this next line to test, and it indeed does what you'd expect, I see "Not Found". 
  // echo "Not Found"; exit;  

  $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();
      $response->redirect([
    "for" => "index", 
    "controller" => "index", 
    "action" => "route404"]
  );

  return; // i return here so it won't run the code after this if statement.
}
```

Any ideas?  The page is completely blank (nothing in source) and there are no errors in my apache logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try returning the response object, not just a blank return. Example:

```
return $this->response->redirect(...);
```

**However** I would recommend to use **Forward from dispatcher** to show 404 pages. This way user will stay on same url and browser will receive the correct status code (404). Also it's SEO friendly this way :)

Example:

```
if ($somethingFailed) {
    return $this->dispatcher->forward(['controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'error404']);
}  

// Controller method
function error404Action()
{   
    $this->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found"); 
    $this->view->pick(['_layouts/error-404']);
    $this->response->send();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  Your recommendation was exactly what I was looking for!  I ended up adding a `notFound()` method to the ControllerBase just to make it easier to use from multiple controllers/locations.  Thanks! =)

Comment: Glad i helped, with forward you hit two rabbits with one stone: little more usability for the user and making those seo experts happy :)