# How to response a 404 page in phalcon?

Tags: phalcon

When id is not exists,I want to response a 404 page to client.

```
$something = Something::findFirst($id);
if (!$something) {
    //response a 404 page
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in a controller

```
$something = Something::findFirst($id);
if (!$something) {
    return $this->response->redirect('/404');
}
```

or you can forward to a different action using the dispatcher

```
$this->dispatcher->forward(
    [
        'controller' => 'utils',
        'action'     => 'notfound',
    ]
);
```

Comment: The url will change to `/404` that is not what i want.

Comment: Try the `forward` method on the dispatcher. I changed my comment to show you how

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `forward()` method from Dispatcher class.

```
if ($somethingFailed) {
    return $this->dispatcher->forward(['controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'error404']);
}  

// Controller method
function error404Action()
{   
    $this->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found"); 
    $this->view->pick('_layouts/error-404');
    $this->response->send();
}
```

Question with similar problem: [Redirecting to 404 route in PhalconPHP results in Blank Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291787/redirecting-to-404-route-in-phalconphp-results-in-blank-page/36301058#36301058)